# Are pre-installed 3DS games tied to my account or the console itself?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Nintendo is selling 3DS XLs with a game pre-installed. I am curious what the situation with that is. Is the game tied to the console ID, my Nintendo account or is it just a file on the 3DS that is gone forever when deleted?

Comment: Does http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115032/do-i-keep-pre-installed-games-when-transferring-from-one-3ds-to-another?rq=1 contain an answer to your question?  A pre-installed game would transfer to a new console when you do a system transfer.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that it's possible to re-download from the eshop if it gets deleted:

http://techforums.nintendo.com/thread/18680

Like other 3DS download games, it seems to be tied to the system itself rather than your account, but is likely transferable if you do a system transfer to another system.