# Do I keep pre-installed games when transferring from one 3DS to another?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I have a Nintendo 3DS with lots of games and stuff on, and recently bought the Limited Edition 3DS XL which has Fire Emblem: Awakening pre-installed.

If I transfer all my stuff from the 3DS to the 3DS XL, will the Fire Emblem game still be there?

The manual didn't seem 100% clear as to what happens to existing games.

Comment: I'd certainly assume they'd be treated like other downloaded games, but I haven't tried such a transfer myself so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [Nintendo's own FAQ](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/3ds/en_na/gi_index.jsp) (Click *General Information* -> *What Is Transferred During the System Transfer Process?*), you will keep your game on the target system, and be able to redownload it from the eShop, see the two excerpts from the answer:

> **What Is Transferred During the System Transfer Process?**
>   Applies To: Transfer From Nintendo 3DS
>   **Answer:**
>   For the most part, information on the target system (system being transferred to) will be overwritten by the information on the source system (system being transferred from). See below for specific details, or [click here](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/3ds/en_na/data_transfer.jsp) for more information:
>   - **All content downloaded via the eShop on both systems (DSiWare, Ambassador games and status, 3DS Downloadable software, etc) will be combined together onto the target system.**
>   - After the transfer is complete, titles will be available to re-download from the Nintendo eShop on the target system.
>   [...]
>   - **Pre-installed games** [...] **are treated as a standard Nintendo eShop game license.**
>   [...]

Comment: I can confirm this information is accurate. We transferred a ambassador 3DS to a new 3DS XL when MH3U came out.