# Transfer all data EXCEPT pre-installed game (and possibly that game's data) from one 3DS to another

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

As mentioned in my other questions, I currently have an Animal Crossing 3DS-XL that came with Animal Crossing New Leaf pre-loaded on there.  I want to transfer my data to a New 3DS (the New model), which means I'll be migrating my Nintendo ID as well of course.

Through various [other](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115032/do-i-keep-pre-installed-games-when-transferring-from-one-3ds-to-another) answered [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352719/are-you-able-to-delete-a-pre-loaded-game-from-your-3ds-how-do-you-re-download-i/353022#353022), it seems that the process to transfer all of this is relatively simple (at least by Nintendo standards) as the game becomes tied to your Nintendo ID and is treated like an eShop game, but some other [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94757/are-pre-installed-3ds-games-tied-to-my-account-or-the-console-itself?noredirect=1&lq=1) have mentioned that pre-installed games are tied to the system, NOT the ID.

So let's say I wanted to transfer all of my data, eShop games, themes, etc. & Nintendo ID to my new 3DS but I wanted to create another Nintendo ID for my Animal Crossing 3DS and keep the pre-loaded game installed WITH the save data (if possible).

**The process broken down looks like this.**

- I have my current Animal Crossing 3DS with NNID, all games, pre-loaded AC:NL
- I have a new, unopened NEW Nintendo 3DS (*I dislike their terminology*)
- I transfer all data and my NNID to NEW 3DS
- I create a new NNID on the original Animal Crossing 3DS

  - I am able to play the pre-loaded Animal Crossing: New Leaf with a existing save or create a new one. (Both possible? One?  Neither?)

Is there a way to do this?  Or will the transfer process move the pre-installed Animal Crossing license to the new system with my Nintendo ID?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the quickest way to figure this out would be to call Nintendo Support at 1-800-255-3700. That way you get a quick answer and a walkthrough.