# If I have a preinstalled game on the device, then I reformat my system, will the game still be on it?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Will I lose a preinstalled game if I reformat the system? I am going to sell mine, and I don't want to lose the game.

Comment: Possibly related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94757/are-pre-installed-3ds-games-tied-to-my-account-or-the-console-itself?rq=1

Comment: @Angzuril It seems like it is ok to format, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

A preinstalled game works slightly differently than a game you've bought. The game is actually tied to the console itself.

If you reformat the system, the game will still be accessible from that console.

I bought the special 20th anniversary Pokémon 3DS with Pokémon Red and Blue preinstalled on it. I had to reformat the system after accidentally creating a new Nintendo account before transferring my account from my old 3DS to it, but after transferring the account, I was able to redownload Pokémon Red and Blue free of charge.

For reference, users [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997614-nintendo-3ds/73368793) support what I've said.

> I did a similar thing with Mine (upgraded the memory card). When I spoke to ninteno the guy claimed **the games are tied to your systems license**. So I should be able to connect to the eshop and redownload at no charge
>
> When you perform a system transfer, pre-installed games can ALWAYS be re-downloaded at no charge on the eShop for free.